# How to loop through various endpoints in a specific order

Tags: angularjs, angular, typescript

I have various endpoints that I need to test under different login credentials. I am currently looping through all of the end points but the results don't appear in the order that they are called as they are async.

I need to loop through each end point using specific password and push the results of the end point to array1 then get the results of the endpoint using password2 and push that to array2.

array1 should equal the results of all end point using password1
array2 should equal the results of all end point using password2

```
public runTests(endPoints, pass1, pass2):void {
  for (let i = 0; i < endPoints.length; i++) {
   this.test(endPoints[i], user1, pass1).then(result => {
    this.array1.push(result);
   });

   this.test(endPoints[i], user2, pass2).then(result => {
    this.array2.push(result);
   });
  }
}
```

I am currently getting the results from all the end points I am trying to test successfully just not to sure how I would store them in the arrays in the order in which they are called any advice and or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your both `this.test` async function call into blocked scope to preserve value of `i`, by having self executing function in a place.

**Code**

```
public runTests(endPoints, pass1, pass2): void {
  for (let i = 0; i < endPoints.length; i++) {
    //self executing function
    ((index) => {
      this.test(endPoints[index], user1, pass1).then(result => {
        this.array1.push(result);
      });

      this.test(endPoints[index], user2, pass2).then(result => {
        this.array2.push(result);
      });
    })(i); //passing value of `i`.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To call all promises in same order you can use `Promise` with it's support to chain other promises in single flow in strict order using `then`:

```
var p = new Promise();

for (let i = 0; i < endPoints.length; i++) {
   p = p.then(function(index) {
     return this.test(endPoints[index], user1, pass1).then(result => {
       array1.push(result);
     })
   })(i));
}

p.then(function() {console.log(array1});
```

Also, pay attention, you need to wrap your async call into IIFE function to create closure and avoid problems with getting scoped `i`.

Comment: let p = new Promise(); throws an error supplied params do not match any signature of call target